# How to introduce auxiliary variables to make the objective function separable?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the objective function

$$\min_{X}\|X_{(1)}\|_{*}+\|X_{(2)}\|_{*}+\|X_{(3)}\|_{*}+\lambda\|Ax-b\|_2^2$$

where $X$ is a three order tensor, $X_{(i)}$ is a matrix whose columns are the mode-$i$ fibers of $X$(i=1,2,3), $x$ is vec($X$), $\lambda$ is constant, and $\|\cdot\|_*$ is the nuclear norm.

How to introduce auxiliary variables to make the objective function separable?

Comment: You must introduce equality constraints to do so. May I assume that is acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & \|Z_1\|_* + \|Z_2\|_* + \|Z_3\|_* + \lambda\|A\mathop{\textrm{vec}}(X) - b \|_2^2 \\
\text{subject to} & Z_1 = X_{(1)} \\
                  & Z_2 = X_{(2)} \\
                  & Z_3 = X_{(3)}
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you！ I'd like to reformulate my model as the following linearly constrained separable convex program:$$\min_{x_{1},...x_{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}(x_{i}),   s.t. \sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal A_{i}(x_{i})=b$$ where $f_{i}$ is a convex function, $\mathcal A_{i}$ is a linear mapping.

Comment: Yes that's what I've done.